# Why were Saints risen after the death of Jesus?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew

In Matthew Chapter 27, Verses 52-53 King James,

> And the graves were opened; and many bodies of the Saints which slept
>   arose (53) And came out of the graves after His resurrection, and went
>   into the holy city, and appeared unto many.

This is all given about the subject, since none of the other gospels mention this event. Though I know it wasn't a sort of soul sleep, it still confuses me on *why* they rose from the grave. Does anyone know?

Comment: Some things are simply shrouded in mystery.

Comment: This question isn't a great fit for this site, because there are many opinions and you don't ask for a particular viewpoint or a particular tradition's viewpoint.  But also, it has already been asked: [What is the significance of dead saints being resurrected to life at the crucifixion of Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17989/21576)

Comment: I think it was a forshadowing.